# Discord Unban All User command ( js )

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Just a simple unban all users in guild command for my next ban royale in Discord. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please view [how to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I wrote this based on the fact that you were writing your bot in discord.js as you did not give much information when writing and all i could see was the tags.*
Try this-

```
    const member = message.member; 
    switch(message.content.toLowerCase()){
    case (!"unban all"):
        if(member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){
            message.guild.fetchBans().forEach((fB)=>{
                message.guild.members.unban(fB.user.id);
            })
            // All Users get unbanned
        } else {
            // User does not have permission.
        }
    }
})
```

If this does not work please let me know.
P.S. I'm kinda new to coding so if it is wrong please don't be angry with me.